# Filter results in ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

i have a shiny app [Item Correlation](https://abdalmoamen95.shinyapps.io/CorrelationApp/) which get the correlation between several products.
and i want to get only the values which's more than zero without removing the sorted results.
and  this's my server code:

```
server <- function(input,output){
  data<- reactive({
    input$Item
  })
  output$Itemcorr <- renderTable({
    DF %>% filter(FirstItem == data())  %>% arrange(desc(X.Correlation))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    barplot(subset(DF$X.Correlation, DF$FirstItem == data()),main="X.Correlation Distribution", 
            xlab="SecondItems",ylab="Percent",xlim=c(1,60),ylim = c(0,100), col=c("darkblue","red"),names.arg =subset(DF$SecondItem, DF$FirstItem == data())
    )
  })
```

Comment: Could you mention the problem in the code

Comment: There's no problem with is i want to add new filter in it to get only the values of x.Correlation > 0

Comment: In that case, `%>% filter(x.Correlation > 0)` or use that in the first `filter`  i.e. `%>% filter(FirstItem == data(), x.Correlation > 0) %>%`

Comment: how can i use it in the **output$Itemcorr** and **output$plot** in the same time

Comment: Perhaps you can put that in a reactive `df1 <- reactive({DF %>% filter(FirstItem == data(), x.Correlation > 0)  %>% arrange(desc(X.Correlation))
  }); output$Itemcorr <- renderTable({df1()})` and same with `output$plot`  I can't test your code without a reproducible example

Comment: i should add this df1 in the existing reactive or i should add it in a separate one ?

Comment: didn't saw your earlier reactive.  You can add those inside the reactive i.e. `DF %>% filter(FirstItem == input$Item, x.Correlation > 0) %>% arrange(desc(X.Correlation))`  Now you can use `data()` inside the `renderTable` and also in `plot`

Comment: but in the plot i need  to get the column of X.Correlation to put it on hight not all data in output$Itemcorr

Comment: You can subset it with `data()$X.Correlation`

Comment: OK I'll try it now

Comment: Awesome its working fine, thanks very much @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a couple of things here,

1) create the second condition also in the same `filter`

2) In the `reactive` call we do the data subsetting

```
server <- function(input,output){

 data<- reactive({
    DF %>% 
       filter(FirstItem == input$Item, X.Correlation > 0) %>% 
       arrange(desc(X.Correlation))
    })

 output$Itemcorr <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

 output$plot <- renderPlot({
    barplot(data()$X.Correlation),main="X.Correlation Distribution", 
            xlab="SecondItems",ylab="Percent",xlim=c(1,60),ylim = c(0,100),
    col=c("darkblue","red"),names.arg =data()$SecondItem)
    )
  })
```